Is it possible to generating Excel documents with outline column groups from table components in Jasper?
I would like to create an excel export in Jasper, and I would like to know if it is possible to create groups that can be opened and closed in columns, as shown in the picture.

I  know that it is possible to do this for rows:
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.row.outline.level.3" value="End"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.row.outline.level.2" value="Body"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.row.outline.level.1" value="Body"/>

However, I want to do this horizontally, on columns.
If possible, could you write some examples how to do it?
Thank you very much!
